# Make my Raspberry Pi 3 safely accessible from outside my local network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, remote-access, hardware-rec, iot

I have a [Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.zdnet.com/article/what-is-the-raspberry-pi-3-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-tiny-low-cost-computer/) at home, and I want to use it to control some devices there. with remote access via the Internet so I can monitor and control those devices when away. What are the best practices to secure the connection?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: See https://blog.hackster.io/pivpn-makes-it-easier-than-ever-to-gain-secure-remote-access-to-your-raspberry-pi-de7f26e3e9a1

Comment: @K7AAY thank you, i'm definitely going to try it. I also found this cloud 3rd party service remote.it that I'm currently exploring.

Comment: OpenVPN or OpenSSH.  If using OpenSSH, here's a [server config](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/BSD-Linux/sshd_config) I always recommend, as I configured it to be a secure config to build off of.

Answer (score 1):

Please also have a look [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/setting-up-ssh-over-internet-on-my-pi). The basic idea is that you have to somehow assign an internet accesible address to your home network.